# Predicted treatment effect for causally related conditions

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, causality, hierarchical-bayesian, meta-regression

Let's say there are two medical conditions $A$ and $B$ that are causally-related, i.e. that they share a common etiological process $C$. For example, $A$ and $B$ could be related autoimmune conditions like multiple sclerosis (MS) and neuromylelitis optica (NMO) and factor $C$ would be some shared dysfunction of the immune system. Or another example would be two different subtypes of a particular kind of cancer. Because of this $A$ and $B$ are statistically associated. Let's say we do some epidemiological and genetic studies and use a latent variable model to infer the variance of $A$ and $B$ explained by $C$, denoted $v_{ac}$ and $v_{bc}$. From a hierarchical modeling standpoint, we posit that e.g. cancer subtypes $A$ and $B$ have some distinct characteristics but also have significant commonalities, so a drug that targets the common etiological process $C$ would be expected to have an effect on both.

Let's say I have done an RCT of $T_1$ on condition $A$ and another RCT of $T_1$ on condition B and get a different effect size of $d_2 = 0.8$ with some standard error for the latter. Given a causal model of how $A$ and $B$ are related, how can I pool these effect sizes to get smaller confidence/credible intervals for both (i.e. a kind of meta-analysis) under the assumption that the treatment is targeting the common ancestor of both subconditions?